# Splitting a string variable in Stata, and placing values in order

Tags: stata

Splitting a string variable in Stata is generally easy to do. However, in my case, I have trouble reorganizing the order of these values. The variable represents a list of characteristics associated with an observation and looks like this:

```
Variable_Name
No Phosphates
No Perfumes; No Phosphates; Private Label
No Perfumes; Private Label
Private Label
```

If I use the code `split Variable_Name, p("; ")`, I get

```
Variable_Name1      Variable_Name2      Variable_Name2 
No Phosphates              
No Perfumes         No Phosphates       Private Label
No Perfumes         Private Label       
Private Label
```

How to rearrange the values so that it looks something like this?

```
Variable_Name1      Variable_Name2        Variable_Name3        
No Phosphates              
No Phosphates       No Perfumes            Private Label
                    No Perfumes            Private Label      
                                           Private Label
```

In other words, how to group the same characteristics under the same column?

Here is a full code:

```
clear
input str50 Variable_Name 
"No Phosphates"
"No Perfumes; No Phosphates; Private Label"
"No Perfumes; Private Label"
"Private Label"
end

split Variable_Name, p("; ")
```

The challenge is that I have an unknown number of characteristics. It will be impossible for me to manually identify and sort them into columns by hand, or looking up certain string values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/problems-with-reshape/) for some `reshape` technique. Note that this will be entirely sensitive to small differences in spelling, etc.

```
clear 
input str100 what 
"No Phosphates"
"No Perfumes; No Phosphates; Private Label"
"No Perfumes; Private Label"
"Private Label"
end 
split what, p(;) 
rename what original 
gen id = _n
reshape long what, i(id) 
replace what = trim(what) 
egen group = group(what) 
drop if missing(group) 
drop _j 
reshape wide what, i(id) j(group) 
list
```